Filtering accumulated errors with kotlin arrow
I am working on a kotlin application as part of an AWS-Lambda. The application needs to run some functions and keep track of any errors raised. However, not all error types should result in a failure state. For these types of errors, we want to treat the final state of the lambda as a success *** and send an email with information about what went wrong.
What I am trying to figure out is what is the best way to filter the errors to produce the outcome I want. Lets take a super simple example. The input is a collection of integers. If any value is less than 0, treat it as a logical error and the lambda fails. If the collection contains any odd values, collect those errors but do not fail the lambda. If all values are even and greater than or equal to zero, the lambda succeeds and no email gets sent. My code then looks like:
fun checkAllEvenError( inputs:List<Int>): Either<NonEmptyList<Throwable>, List<Any>>
{
    val v1:Either<NonEmptyList<Throwable>, List<Any>> = inputs.mapOrAccumulate<Throwable, Int, Any> {
        checkEvenError(it).bind()
    }
    return v1
}

fun checkEvenError( value:Int):Either<Throwable, Any>
{
    if(value < 0)
    {
        return Either.Left( Throwable( "${value.toString()} is negative!", ))
    }
    else if( value % 2 != 0 )
    {
        return Either.Left( TestError( "${value.toString()} not even!", value.toString()))
    }
    else
    {
        return Either.Right("${value.toString()} even")
    }
}

@Test
fun testMapOrAccumulateError()
{
    val inputs = listOf(-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5)
    checkAllEvenError(inputs).fold(
        {
            errors:List<Throwable>->
            println("left: $errors")
            assertThat(errors).doesNotHaveAnyElementsOfTypes(TestInterface::class.java) },
        { 
            println("right: $it")
            fail("test should have thrown an error")
        })
}

For a simple case like this, the obvious solution is to change

    else if( value % 2 != 0 )
    {
        return Either.Left( TestError( "${value.toString()} not even!", value.toString()))
    }


to

    else if( value % 2 != 0 )
    {
        return Either.Right( TestError( "${value.toString()} not even!", value.toString()))
    }


however in the real application, the call chain is more complicated. I would prefer to let the errors bubble up and handle them later.
So, what is the approach here? Should I do filtering on the errors after they have been accumulated? are there any existing arrow functions to filter in this way?
*** they indicate invalid input data, so there is no point in the lambda re-trying since it will produce the same results.

After I lot of trial and error I found something that works. That said, I'm sure there must be a nicer way to do this. I will leave the question open in case someone can find a better solution.
fun checkAllEvenError( inputs:List<Int>): Either<NonEmptyList<Any>, List<Any>>
    {
        val v1 = inputs.mapOrAccumulate<Throwable, Int, Any> {
            checkEvenError(it).bind()
        }.fold(  { it->
               it.map { throwable ->
                   if (throwable is TestInterface) {
                      throwable
                   } else {
                       raise(throwable)
                   }
               }.right()
            },{
                it.right()
            })
    return v1
    }

